# TypeError : Method Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString called on incompatible receiver undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to show the current time of the system when user click on the button but I am getting this error.
TypeError
Method Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString called on incompatible receiver undefined

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  let curr = new Date().toLocaleTimeString;
  const [current, setTime] = useState(curr);

  const getTime = () => {
    let newcurr = new Date().toLocaleTimeString;
    setTime(newcurr);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{current}</h1>
      <button onClick={getTime}>GET TIME</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all here you're passing the method itself without binding `this` to it:

```js
    let curr = new Date().toLocaleTimeString;
    const [current, setTime] = useState(curr);
```

It should be something like this:

```js
    const [current, setTime] = useState(() => new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```

Notice how I use a value-generating function to execute its code on the first call only. And also it's almost the same here:

```js
    let newcurr = new Date().toLocaleTimeString;
    setTime(newcurr);
```

Must be:

```js
    setTime(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```